# About ViewGroup.requestLayout()

Tags: android

I have a custom viewGroup like this

```
public class CustomLinearLayout extends LinearLayout {
public CustomLinearLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public CustomLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
protected void onWindowVisibilityChanged(int visibility) {
    super.onWindowVisibilityChanged(visibility);
    requestLayout();
    System.out.println("right after request layout");
}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
    System.out.println("on layout");
}
```

}

When i run this app,i found the log like this :
[image]
How could this happen ? the `onLayout()` runs after the `System.out.println("right after request layout");`。
Could anybody tell me why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#requestLayout()

> "Call this when something has changed which has invalidated the layout
>   of this view. This will schedule a layout pass of the view tree."

The `requestLayout()` call only schedules a layout pass, but does not do it immediately.